# How to convert a UTC timestamp to a named timezone in SAP SQL Anywhere?

Tags: sql, datetime, timezone, sqlanywhere

I'm using SAP SQL Anywhere 17 and have a timestamp (without time zone) which I know is UTC, and I know that my client's browser reports a time zone of "Europe/Berlin".

Is there an easy way to convert the UTC timestamp to a local timestamp of this time zone using SQL? Let's assume that I have already [created the timezone](https://help.sap.com/viewer/93079d4ba8e44920ae63ffb4def91f5b/17.0/en-US/c3887dce94ba1014bf4c8fcd9b823dbd.html) with

`CREATE TIME ZONE "Europe/Berlin" OFFSET '01:00'  DST OFFSET '01:00' DST STARTING 'Mar/last Sun' AT '02:00' DST ENDING 'Oct/last Sun' AT '02:00';`

I guess it is possible to do it manually using the SYSTIMEZONE view, but it is some hours of hard work to handle all the special cases! Maybe someone has done it already, or Anywhere provides a system function which I have overlooked in the docs.

Note that the problem is to find out whether DST is active at an arbitrary UTC timestamp. Using just the *current* offset will give wrong results if the timestamp is, for example, 6 months in the future!

Answer (score 0):

When the timezone is activated on your server you have a connection property called `TimeZoneAdjustment` that returns the number of **minutes** relative to UTC. For Europe/Berlin this is "60" (during winter time/standard time).

You could add that offset *manually* using the `DATEADD` function:

```sql
SELECT CURRENT UTC TIMESTAMP AS my_utc_timestamp,
       DATEADD(minute, CONNECTION_PROPERTY('TimeZoneAdjustment'), my_utc_timestamp) AS localtime
```

Newer versions of SQL Anywhere 17 have a new function `TOLOCALDATE` that automatically applies the current connection's offset to an UTC timestamp (although I couldn't test that function cause my version is to old).

Comment: This function uses the *current* timezone offset, so using it to convert an arbitrary timestamp (which might be 6 months ago or in the future) is not correct, since daylight saving status, and therefor the offset in minutes, will probably different from today's offset.