# Timezone Conversion Function

Tags: sqlanywhere

I have a requirement.
I will provide input as date and time.
My Function must return the date and time of that particular location.
But, my db and computer will be at same date and time only

I need in Sql Anywhere

Thanks,
Nirmal

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Look at my answer for this related question - is this something you could use? https://stackoverflow.com/a/70607406/383529